# Avoiding duplicates

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, duplicates

Imagine that we have a file, and some job that processes it and sends the data:

1. into the database
2. to an external service

Can we guarantee to process the file only once or at least to determine that something went wrong and notify the user so that he manually solved this problem?

Comment: who places the file in there? I mean by someone ? or some other process doss that ?

Comment: @UsmanRana, yes, it's a different process

Comment: Do the lines of data you create have any sort of unique identifier? What about the files? Do you need to worry about reprocessing a file that partially completed previously?

Comment: @TracyMoody, There are no unique identifiers. Data must be fully processed without duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

What you can do is create a table in the database to store the name and a flag/status (if read, yes else no) of files. When process feeds the file in that location, make sure that the same process updates the name (if name is different each time) and flag/status for that file in the database. Your file read process can get the name of file from the database and dump that file in wherever you ant and when it's done, It should update the flag to `read` or whatever. This way, you can avoid reading the file more than one time.

Answer (score 0):

I would store two tables of information in your database.

1. The processed file lines like you were already doing.
2. A record of the files themselves. Include:

   - the filename
   - whether the processing was successful, failed, partially succeeded
   - a `SHA1` hashed checksum that can be used to check for the uniqueness of the file later

When you go to process a file, you first check whether the checksum already exists. If it does, you can stop processing and log the issue. Or you can throw that information on the file table.

Also be sure to have a foreign key association between your processed lines and your files. That way if something does go wrong, the person doing manual intervention can trace the affected lines.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Usmana or Tracy answer actually guarantees that a file is not processed more than once and your job doesn't send duplicate requests to the database and the external service(#1 and #2 in your question). Both solutions suggest keeping a log and update it after all the processing is done but if an error occurs when you try to update the log at the very end, your job will try processing the file again next time it runs and will send duplicate requests to the database and external service. The only way to deal with it using the solutions Usmana and Tracy suggested is to run everything in a transaction but it's quite a challenging task in a distributing environment like yours.

A common solution to your problem is to gracefully handle duplicate requests to the database and external services. The actual implementation can vary but for example you can add a unique constraint to the database and when the job tries to insert a duplicate record an exception will be thrown which you can just ignore in the job because it means the required data is already in the db.

My answer don't mean that you don't need the log table Usmana and Tracy suggested. You do need it to keep track of processing status but it doesn't really guarantee there won't be duplicate requests to your database and external service unless you use a distributed transaction.

Hope it helps!